# Copy Text to clipboard using HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, button, clipboard

How do I actually copy some fixed text to clipboard using javascript?

This is my code and it's not working maybe there's another way and I don't know.

```
<button onclick="Copy()">Copy</button>
<script>
function Copy() {
document.execCommand("copy","Some text here");
}    
</script>
```

I want to copy some fixed text using just button, so I don't have to select texts manually and copy them.
Thanks.

Comment: What text are you trying to copy? Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem you are having and be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I believe there is a minimal example above. `"Some text here"` is not being copied to the clipboard as expected.

Comment: @JeremyThille You're right, I had thought they were trying to copy text from another element.

Comment: I was trying to copy some text that are hidden from a user's input and interface so i do not have to select them manually thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```js
var copy_text_val = document.querySelector('.copy_text');

function Copy() {
  copy_text_val.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(copy_text_val.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Copy()">Copy</button>
<input type="text" class="copy_text" value="blablabla">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

```
<script>
    function Copy() {
     var copyText = document.createElement("input");                  
     copyText.style="display:none";
     copyText.value  = "This is a paragraph";     
     document.body.appendChild(copyText); 
     copyText.select();
     copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
     document.execCommand("copy");
     alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this action you have to select the text dynamically before actually copying it:
Here is an example:

```js
function copy_text(node){
    if(document.body.createTextRange){
        const range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    else if(window.getSelection){
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(node);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    else {
        console.warn("Could not select text in node");
    }
}
// This copy_text function ensures cross-browser compatibility
// What it does is select the text within the range of the node holding the text
// Then executes the "copy" command on that selected text

function clear_selection(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        document.selection.empty();
    }
}
// This clear_selection function clears any selection from the document

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementById("clipboard-exec").onclick = function(){
        copy_text(document.getElementById("clipboard-text"));
        // Copy the text on clicking the button
        setTimeout(() => { clear_selection() }, 500);
        // Clear the selection after 0.5s
    }
});
```

```html
<span id="clipboard-text">This is the text that will be copied to your clipboard when you click on the "Copy" button.</span>
<button><span id="clipboard-exec"><i class="fa fa-copy"> Copy</i></span></button>
```

Of course with this function you can just restructure it to fit your needs.
Also note that what you are trying to accomplish by copying directly to the keyboard without a valid text node actually holding the text won't work, I guess for security purposes

But you can create a node in the document with the text but hide it from view then select it using this function .. **NOTE** the text you are copying to the clipboard has to be actually in the document, for you to execute the "copy" command on it